# SqlQuery in EntityFramework with sql command including non mapped table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to run a SQL statement in a EntityFramework DbContext, but I don't get the expected result compared with the same query executed in SQL Management Studio. Zero result run in code and 3 run in SQL-MS.

The calling methods looks like:

```
 internal List<AddressZ> BaseAddresses(string email)
 {
     string sql = @"select * from [Address] where Email = 'Email@example.com' AND Id not in
     (
       select [Address].Id from [Address] 
       inner join [Order] on [Order].ShippingAddressId = [Address].Id OR
                             [Order].BillingAddressId = [Address].Id
       where Email = 'Email@example.com'
     )";
     return context.SqlQuery<AddressZ>(sql, new object[]{}).ToList();
 }
```

The context object is an implementation of DbContext. The returntype "AddressZ" is mapped in the context, but the table "[Order]" is not mapped in the Context and is not used, except in the database query (I suppose it's executed at the database).

```
class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressZMap());
    }

    public IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return base.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, parameters);            
    }
}
```

I could map the table [Order], but I prefer to avoid that. Is there a possible solution to my problem?

Comment: Try selecting a single column from Address (such as Email) and change the element type in SqlQuery<TElement> to string. Does it now return the expected number of results? If yes, it's the AddressZ mapping that is the issue.